# Asking a question that was asked on another stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it acceptable to ask a question on skeptics.SE if the same question was asked on another stackexchange site?

I'm thinking about [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/does-being-cold-help-lose-weight). There is an accepted answer, but it makes a few unverified assumptions  and would be of strictly no value on skeptics.SE...

Answer (score 3):

It is acceptable, however I think that at least one answer over there would also be good enough here: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/1037

Comment: meh, this answer seems to assume that the human body will actively consume energy to heat up the water... But I think that what might happen is that the body will in fact use other methods (such as sweating less, taking blood away from the surface of your skin, you hands, feet, ears, etc. to make sure your vital organs are at a high enough temperature...)

Comment: I'd say: prove me wrong @Uwat

Comment: @IvoFlipse the human body has [many ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoregulation#In_cold_conditions) to fight cold temperatures. Your answer assumes that 100% of the difference in temperature is compensated by the way #5 in the link. But I would think that the body would naturally try to keep its fat reserves so it would try to use other methods first... 

Off course I did not show that your answer is wrong, but I have proven that it far from being necessarily correct.

Comment: My answer simply shows how stupid it is to try and lose weight by cooling your body. Given an accurate estimate it virtually impossible given how many variables are involved