# Is a highly upvoted question discussed and answered on another SE enough to show notability?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, notability

This question is related to [this question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/asking-a-question-that-was-asked-on-another-stackexchange-site).

Is a question asked on any other SE site that has generated upvotes and an accepted answer with upvotes enough for notability?

Sometimes it can be hard (surprisingly!) to find references that people believe a certain thing or not. If a question/answer is upvoted and comments show that people believe the claim to be true, is that sufficient to then ask on Skeptics.SE (assuming the original answer was insufficient)?

If the answer is no, then why would an up-voted accepted answer on another SE site not be sufficient, yet Yahoo Answers answers are?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable (the answer is quite clearly spelt out: no it's not enough)

Comment: @Sklivvz I hadn't thought a question could be a duplicate of a FAQ.  Notability is about showing people believe something to be true. Why would an upvoted, accepted answer on another SE site not meet that criteria, when Yahoo Answers answers are acceptable?

Comment: I also don't understand the downvote. It is unnecessarily hostile. I'm asking a question, not arguing a point one way or the other.

Comment: Nobody said that Yahoo Answers are acceptable by themselves. It's a matter of degrees. In any case another question does not represent a valid precedent by itself. E.g. if I go and ask a question on, say, Biology, then does that make the same question notable on Skeptics? Of course, not.

Comment: @Sklivvz, little more than Yahoo Answers were used to justify the atom question being notable. The way I read Borror0's [answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/are-stereotypes-and-tropes-notable-claims) to the question about tropes being notable is that a few Yahoo Answers would be sufficient for notability. A question being asked on another SE site would not make it notable, but the up-votes and acceptance might.

Answer (score 2):

Its going to depend on the claim and the question.  Is the claim specifically made(not inferred from the answer) and is it a claim of fact not opinion the I would say yes.  If there is a question of fact or opinion err to the side of it is opinion.

If the answer is being used to deduce a claim for a question then no it is not acceptable.  The claim must be specific and fact based.

Comment: What about an answer saying that something is possible, being highly upvated? It is not a direct claim being stated but it shows that a lot of people beieve it to be the case.

Comment: No it means that people think that it is a good answer.  That does not mean they believe it.  That is a deduced claim.  An accepted answer would be.  Err to the side of extreme caution.  You have a bad reputation with users so anything YOU post is likely to be met with hostility if it is not well inside the lines.

Comment: How about you keep your opinons to a minimum? I was just trying to clarify your answer, no need for hostility.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell - I was trying to help you.